# События в кнопке (onkeydown, onclick)

Tags: c#, события, button

Необходимо реализовать действие после нажатия на кнопку **И кликом И клавиатурой**.
Я приписала два события `OnCliCk()` и `KeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)`

Если пользователь нажимает на Enter то Onclick тоже срабатывает, следом и то дублируется, что изначально планировалось делать единожды. Как же я могу реализовать данную задачу ?
почему срабатывает OnClick, ведь я же не кликаю мышкой, а нажимаю на клавиатуре Enter. Я пробовала убрать Onclick, но тогда пользователь ограничен только клавиатурой. А как я могу реализовать два события, чтоб сработало какое то действие **НО только один раз**, а не дублировалось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если пользователь нажимает клавиатуру = Enter, то OnKeyDown срабатывает и если мышкой то OnClick

```
@page "/"

@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

@{
    <p>какой то текст</p>
    <button>кнопка точка отступа, чтоб табуляцию переключить</button>
    <button @onkeydown="@((e)=>KeyDown(e))"
    @onclick="@(()=>OnCliCk())">Test event with keyboard</button>
}

@code{
    public async void KeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "KeyDown!");
        }
    }
    public async void OnCliCk()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "OnClick!");
    }
}
```

[Вот пример на гитхаб,](https://github.com/Dev18000/BtnEventSample/blob/master/BtnEventSample/Pages/Index.razor) я использую блазор для примера, метку блазор не ставлю, потому как это вопрос общий по логике последовательности событий.

наверняка есть способ использовать оба действия для удобства пользователя для кнопки, в документации я не нашла. Подскажите, кто уже делал, как вы решили такую задачу ?
если есть ссылка на документации, то спасибо и за нее

*На простом языке(если на данном примере), мне нужно модальное окно единожды, а не дважды как во втором случае демо*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вспомнил.

Вместо `onclick` используйсте `onmousedown`, тогда событие не будет срабатывать на клаву. А `onclick` срабатывает даже на програмное нажатие `element.click()`.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2akLB.gif отлично теперь нет конфликта событий